# clone within an ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Inspired by the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/34sLv7fm/) , I became able to clone a row in my table.
Here is my code:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="rowContent in rows track by $index" id="{{ 'object-' + $index }}">
    <td>{{rowContent}}</td>
    <td>{{rowContent}}</td>
    <td>{{rowContent}}</td>
    <td>{{rowContent}}</td>
    <td>{{rowContent}}</td>
    <td>{{rowContent}}</td>
    <td>{{rowContent}}</td>
    <td>{{rowContent}}</td>
    <td>{{rowContent}}</td>
    <td>{{rowContent}}</td>
    <td>{{rowContent}}</td>
    <td>{{rowContent}}</td>
    <td>{{rowContent}}</td>
    <td>{{rowContent}}</td>
    <td> <button ng-click="clickToClone(('object-' + $index), 'cloneDiv')">
        Click to Clone
    </button></td>
</tr>

<tr id="cloneDiv"></tr>
```

When I clone the first line everything is alright. However when I clone the second, it is cloned but on the same line with the original element.
The result is in the following screenshot:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jibxS.png)

What should I do please to put the cloned line under not next to the line?

Comment: your fiddle isn't using a ng-repeat, it's different from what you're asking

Comment: seems like you didn't applied the style in fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're inserting the content inside the `tr`, as another column, and actually you should be inserting it after it.

use [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) method instead of `append()`, which is also supported by `jqLite` in `angularJS`

**Edit**

anyway you shouldn't be manipulating the HTML rows directly in your controller. That would cause that, when angular detects a change, re-render `$scope.rows` collection (which haven't been changed in your method) and lost your original row.

What you need to do in your controller is something like (this is pseudo-code)

```
 $scope.clickToClone = function(rowindex)  {
     var rowSource = $scope.rows[rowindex];
     $scope.rows.splice(rowindex, 0, angular.copy(rowSource));
 }
```

updating rows colletion will cause angularJS to re-render the ng-repeat and you'll see the newly added row. Keep in mind that I use `angular.copy()` method just because I don't know if your rows' elements are object, strings, numbers or what. The key point is - update your collection, setting it as how you would like it to be, and let angular to redraw it .

Comment: I used after but when I click to clone a line then when i click to clone a second one, the second clone replace the first

Comment: are you updating your rows collection when clonning ? you shouldn't be manipulating DOM in the controller

Comment: Here is my controller:

$scope.clickToClone = function(sourceId, cloneId) {
            var sourceHtml = angular.element(document.getElementById(sourceId)).html();
            angular.element(document.getElementById(cloneId)).after(sourceHtml);
        }

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am grateful :) !

Comment: I still can not upvote unfortunately I only have five reputations. When i will be able, i will do it ;)